# passing 2d array into a function using only pointer and print the value

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

the result of this program (process 9164) exited with code -1073741819.
the program finished and nothing happens.....what should I do to make it run using only pointer without *x[] or x[][2]

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
void sum(int **x) {
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            cout << *(*(x + i) + j) << " ";
            s += *(*(x + i) + j);
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << s;
}
int main() {
    int x[3][2] = { {11,15},{19,28},{5,8} };
    sum((int**)x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A C-style cast like `(int**)x` can be very dangerous.  The compiler won't tell you that `x` is certainly **not** an `int**`.  Your code never produces any pointer to pointer to int.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you feel the need to do a C-style cast (like you do with `(int**)x`) you should take that as a sign you're doing something wrong.

An array of arrays is *not* the same as a pointer to a pointer.

What happens is that you pass an invalid pointer, and the program will experience *undefined behavior* and *crash*.

What should happen is that the array `x` decay to a pointer to its first element, i.e. plain `x` is the same as `&x[0]`. That will be a pointer to an *array*, with the type `int (*)[2]` (in the case of `x` in your question). That is the type you need to use for the function argument:

```
void sum(int (*x)[2]) { ... }
```

And call like

```
sum(x);
```

---

You can also generalize to accept any kind of "2D" array, by using template arguments for the dimensions and passing the array by reference:

```
// For std::size_t
#include <cstdlib>

template<std::size_t A, std::size_t B>
void sum(int (&x)[A][B])
{
    // Use A and B as the sizes for the arrays...
    ...
}
```

While the above template version is better, the "proper" solution in C++ should be using [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), as in:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 3> = { ... };
```

and then pass it as a constant reference to the function.

If the sizes aren't known at compile-time, or if the arrays should be dynamic, then use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

A good book and and good teacher would teach these classes before going into pointers or C-style arrays.